# Symfony 2: how to have the firewall custom redirect upon custom event

Tags: symfony, firewall, http-redirect

my symfony app deals with multiple "blogs" (multisite wordpress style)

- I have some special status for my blogs among which : **closed_status**.
- I created a Voter for some special rights and that allows me to know if the voter should allow access or not upon verification that the blog we're accessing is open/closed...
  ** example url : http://blog01.myapp.com http://blog18.myapp.com ....
- For now i throw a 403 error and use custom management of 403 exception but i'd like to avoid that and rather redirect at the momment of the voter processing my request.
  ** like what happens when you're not authenticated and you're being redirected to /login or such.

I'm not asking for a full solution, could you just tell me what classes/concepts i should be looking into ?

I thought or listeners+entryPoints thingy but don't really get how it works.

It seems to me that this needAuthentication ==> redirect to login thing is very spécifically coded in symfony.

ps: I'm using fosUserBundle and tried to override as little as i could withing the bundle and concerning hte firewall too.

**The flow i'd like to achieve:**

- request to a blog url
- => myCustomVoter denies and dispatch(CLOSED) or dispatch(PRIVATE) or dispatch(VIPONLY)
- => and it results in a clean redirection to my setpsController actions (defined somewhere)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok,

- I noticed (think) that i can't add a listener to the current firewall (tell me if I'm wrong).
- I also noticed that to do what i want i need to setResponse to a GetResponseEvent.

  - So I just created a generic listener, not attached to the firewall:
  - It listens to my **custom event** and the **kernel.request** that is a GetResponseEvent
  - For now I'm just hopping all will be listened in the order that suits me:

    - my service determinig if the blog is open, public... and that will eventually dispatch my **custom event**
    - my custom listener that will receive the custom event and prepare a response
    - my custom listener that receive the kernel.request and inject my calculated response if it exists

For my first tests it seems to work, but i need to test extensively to be sure that the firewall listeners don't mess with my process (it should not i think)

Here is how i defined my listener.

```
route_access_listener:
    class: [...]\RouteAccessListener
    arguments:
        - @service_container
    tags:
        - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: routeAccessRedirect, method: onCustomRouteAccess }
        - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.request, method: onKernelRequest }
```

Here is the implementation of my listener:

```
[...]

public function onKernelRequest(GetResponseEvent $event)
{
    if($this->response)
        $event->setResponse($this->response);
}

public function onCustomRouteAccess(RouteAccessEvent $event)
{
    $type = $event->getType();

    switch($type){
        case RouteAccessManager::DR_IS_USER_OF_OTHER_BLOG:
            $redirectPath = 'link_to_blog';
            break;

        case RouteAccessManager::DR_BLOG_CLOSED:
            $redirectPath = 'info_closed_blog';
            break;

        case RouteAccessManager::DR_PRIVATE_BLOG:
            $redirectPath = 'info_private_blog';
            break;

        case RouteAccessManager::DR_USER_NOT_ENABLED_BLOG:
            $redirectPath = 'info_not_enabled_on_blog';
            break;

        case RouteAccessManager::DR_INVALID_HOSTNAME:
            $redirectPath = 'info_invalid_hostname';
            break;
    }


    $url = $this->container->get('router')->generate($redirectPath);
    $this->response = new RedirectResponse($url);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Dispatch a custom event in a voter. In the event listener for that event set response to `RedirectResponse`

Comment: I looked for an hour if i could add a listener to the firewall but in the end don't really need to.
The quest for RedirectResponse **in a listener** got me to find a solution